# Можно писать букву "И" в начале предложения??!

Tags: общие-вопросы

Answer (score 6):

Конечно, какие проблемы? **И** может быть *союзом, частицей*.
*И вечный бой! Покой нам только снится...

И как вы думаете исправлять положение? И куда это все запропастились? И погиб казак!**